# Form displays nothing when debugging android in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The form for viewing has textviews, a listview and a button, but it only display a white blank form during debugging.

view_dates_e.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/view_e"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Add Expense" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ViewExpenseDate.java:

```
package com.example.expensetracker1;

import com.example.expensetracker1.helper.SchemaHelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewExpenseDate extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button GoBton;
public void ViewExpDate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_dates_e);//to change
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String date4,cat_a = null,cat_b = null,cat_c = null,cat_d = null,cat_e = null,cat_f=null;
    int a1=0,b1=0,c1=0,d1=0,e1=0,f1=0;
    SchemaHelper sh = new SchemaHelper(this);

    TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    date4 = bundle.getString("Date");
    Toast msg2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selected Date : \n"+date4,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    msg2.show();

    txt1.setText("Today's Expenses : " + date4);

    Cursor c = sh.getDetails(date4);

    while (c.moveToNext()){

        int Cat = c.getColumnIndex(DetailsTable.C_ID);
        int Amt = c.getColumnIndex(DetailsTable.E_Amt);
        int ader = c.getColumnIndex(DetailsTable.O_NAME);
            if(Cat==1){
                a1 = a1+Amt;
                cat_a = "Foods: \n"+a1;
            }else if(Cat==2){
                b1 = b1+Amt;
                cat_b = "Fares: \n"+b1;
            }else if(Cat==3){
                c1 = c1+Amt;
                cat_c = "Bills: \n"+c1;
            }else if(Cat==4){
                d1 = d1+Amt;
                cat_d = "Personal Needs: \n"+d1;    
            }else if(Cat == 5){
                cat_e = "Fares: \n"+e1;
            };
        cat_f=cat_a+"\n"+cat_b+"\n"+cat_c+"\n"+cat_d+"\n"+cat_e+"\n";
        txt2.setText(cat_f);
    }
    GoBton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    GoBton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent view_e = new Intent(v.getContext(),Input_Expense.class);
            startActivity(view_e);
        }
    });
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And, this is the activity before the ViewExpenseDate.java,

Expense_Calendar.java

```
package com.example.expensetracker1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Expense_Calendar extends Activity implements OnClickListener,OnDateChangedListener{

    Button GoBtn;
    DatePicker datepick ;
    int date1,date2,date3;
    Bundle bun = new Bundle();
    Time today;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.expense_calendar_layout);
    today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();

    Toast msg2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Current Date \n"+(today.month+1)+"/"+today.monthDay+"/"+today.year,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    msg2.show();
    //now.set(2015, 1, 12);
    datepick = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

    GoBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    GoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            date1 = datepick.getMonth() + 1;
            date2 = datepick.getDayOfMonth();
            date3 = datepick.getYear();

            int now1 = today.month + 1;  //d.MONTH;
            int now2 = today.monthDay;   //d.DATE;
            int now3 = today.year;  //d.YEAR;

            //converting dates into string
            String now4 = now1+"/"+now2+"/"+now3;
            String date4 = date1+"/"+date2+"/"+date3;

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date convDate1 = new Date();
            Date convDate2 = new Date();

            try {
                convDate1 = dateFormat.parse(now4);
                convDate2 = dateFormat.parse(date4);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (convDate1.equals(convDate2)){
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),ViewExpenseDate.class); 
                bun.putString("Date", date4);
                i.putExtras(bun); 
                startActivity(i);
            }else if (convDate1.after(convDate2)){
                Intent e = new Intent(v.getContext(),ViewExpensePerDate.class);
                bun.putString("Date", date4);
                e.putExtras(bun);     //Pasa ang Date sa Ibang Form
                startActivity(e);
            }else if ( convDate1.before(convDate2)){
                Intent r = new Intent(v.getContext(),ViewReminderDate.class); 
                bun.putString("Date", date4);
                r.putExtras(bun); 
                startActivity(r);
            }   
        }
    });
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

The display of the xml file for Expense_Calendar.java displays just fine during debugging, but upon "if(convDate1.equals(convDate2))" condition is true, the form view_date_e.xml displays next should have some textviews, a listview and a button displaying, but it only displays a blank form.

Any help would be greatly much appreciated

Comment: Where did you place your break point?

Comment: Already solved, thanks anyway :)